# How can I uninstall python3.8 on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, python-3.8

I've done a lot of googling on how to uninstall python3.8 on mac and nothing is working for me.

I don't have it installed as an app and I didn't install it with brew. I think I might have installed it via the installer on pythons website.

My python3 is located at /usr/bin/python3

I don't have permissions to remove that folder. I'd like to remove it and install python3.9 using brew, but I don't want to have multiple versions of python3 lying around.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You very deliberately cannot modify Apple-provided OS components (on modern MacOS releases they're on a read-only filesystem which is signature-checked, causing your system to refuse to boot in the case of tampering). Even on non-MacOS operating systems, it's not good form: on a Linux distro, uninstalling the distro vendor's interpreter will usually break major parts of the operating system, and so one is _only_ expected to add new packages in addition.

Comment: If you want to have an environment in which only the packages you choose can be found in the PATH (the PYTHONPATH, etc), consider installing [Nix](https://nixos.org/) on top of MacOS; if you create a flake with a devShell and then use `nix develop --keep USER --keep HOME --ignore-environment`, f/e, then nothing not specified in that devshell will be in your PATH; for as long as you're in that shell, versions of Python (or other tools) you didn't ask for might as well not exist.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use Miniconda to install different Python versions, and do not remove Apple provided components.

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in /System/Library and /usr/bin, as this may break your whole operating system. You should link the version you want to have, instead of uninstalling apple provided python 3.8.